# c# authenticate phpbb forum user in application

Tags: c#, authentication, phpbb

I would like to have a simple authentication on my software. I know I will need to use HttpWebRequest and send the post data/ headers, but I have not been able to figure it out.... does anyone have any examples?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you encountering? Supply code samples demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the lack of information. I have been able to resolve the issue by creating a custom phpbb forum login php page that takes username / password parameters and I send the request from my software application to this php I've created and wait for the response and see if the php was able to validate the login.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way, Unfortunately I lost my Phpbb application, but it was based on the code provided [Here](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=2132397)

It creates a header for phpbb, and stores the cookies, allowing you to do alot with it.